# rbindlist on 23GB list of data frames

Tags: r, list, data.table, bigdata, rbind

I have a problem with function `rbindlist`. I'm trying to merge large list of size 23.1Gb or bigger with `rbindlist(data.list, fill=T, use.names = T)` but the R session always abort during it. (I have only 8Gb RAM maybe there is a problem.) So how could I merge this big list (or even bigger one)?

It's a list, which I made from real dataset by some transformations etc. and I need to merge it to work with all data (I want to compute cosine similarity etc.)

```
> summary(data.inv[1])
  Length Class      Mode
1 11291  data.frame list

> summary(data.inv[25])
   Length Class      Mode
25 9807   data.frame list

> length(data.inv)
[1] 25
```

Comment: 23 GB won't fit in a 8GB memory. Consider using a data-base, since the object is too large to be handled in RAM.

Comment: @nicola you are right, but there is one problem, I'm building a function, to which you only load the data and the output will be something (not important for this issue) and this `rbindlist` is somewhere in middle of this function.

Comment: @Hack-R done and sorry

Comment: @MartinaZapletalová No, not your fault. I meant that I was opening a discussion on Stack Overflow Meta to have the replace that tag sitewide. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356201/burninate-large-data-tag-or-merge-it-with-bigdata

Comment: There may be a solution here leveraging your storage memory instead of RAM with the `ff` package... hmm. http://user2007.org/program/presentations/adler.pdf